# Installing Qt and getting it to work - must you install MSVC2012 IDE?

Tags: qt, visual-c++

So, like many others I've found on the net, I have installed Qt *(Qt 5.2.1 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, OpenGL, 553 MB))* and realized that I do not have the MSVC2012 compiler that was used to build this version of Qt.

I come here to ask, is it necessary to literally install the entire MSVC2012 IDE in order to get this version of Qt to work, or can I somehow just install the needed compiler? If so, where might that be available for download? I have done searches and cannot find just the compiler. I have found the compiler bundled with various other software that I do not think I need, but I do not want to go through great effort to find out that I made another mistake.

Alternatively, Qt compiled with *minGW* is also available, but only for 32 bit. I understand that *some* 32 bit programs will run on 64 bit machines, but how can you know for sure?

Comment: If a 32-bit program works fine on a 32-bit machine, then it will also work fine on a 64-bit machine. You only have to worry about bitness if you're writing a low-level device driver. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64. In fact, most programs that you install, that don't do heavy number-crunching, are still shipped as 32-bit only -- all programs in your C:\Program Files (x86)\ folder are 32-bit.

Comment: From my personal experience there’s usually no problem in deploying and running 32-bit Qt applications on 64-bit Windows as long as your app carry with the right version of the dlls.

Comment: "entire MSVC2012 IDE in order to get this version of Qt to work, or can I somehow just install the needed compiler" Your question reduces to: does Microsoft distribute an installer that just installs the VC 11 compiler without the IDE. The answer is NO. Alas, why do you care? VS Express is free, and it has everything you need.

Comment: They do have an SDK available, however. I do not like have excessive software on my machine. I am not space limited, but it's just something that I try not to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install Visual Studio 2012 Express which is free and contains the necessary compiler. After that, you have to also install Windows Kits to get the standalone debugger. Alternatively, you can install Windows 7.1 SDK which does not come with IDE but with compilers and debuggers. Windows 7.1 SDK correspond to Visual Studio 2010. But beware, Windows 7.1 SDK has many bugs, and I would not recommend it unless you are targeting Windows XP.

As for MinGW, yes you can also run 32bit programs on 64 bit, but I personally advise you against MinGW. Its integration with Windows is flaky, and its compile speed is far inferior to MSVC's.

Comment: Btw, The MSVC 2012 express can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34673)

Comment: Totally agree. In my opinion this answer should be accepted.